# Get 'Suggested Time' via Google Calendar API

Tags: google-calendar-api

Is there a way to get 'Suggested Time' list programmatically to schedule among multiple attendees, Which API can I use?

A google search for 'google calendar API suggested times' gets me to finding 'free time' via [FreeBusy API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/freebusy/query), which is different from 'Suggested Times' when you are creating an event with attendees

[image: Suggested Time snapshot]

Any pointers to the pertinent API is appreciated.

Thanks,
NT

Comment: there is no suggested time method.  Your going to have to calculate this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

As a community wiki comment:

> there is no suggested time method. Your going to have to calculate this yourself. -> @DaImTo

You can create a feature request for this on [Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191627&template=823906)